# Want to Map AD field account expires with the sys_user table filed which is in Date/Time format in ServiceNow. AD account expires field is in C#

Tags: javascript, active-directory, datetime-format, servicenow

I am unable to resolve this since few days,

I want to calculate when an users account will expires, Coming from AD.

I want a script to calculate when users account will expire and Map it in `sys_user` table field `u_acc_expire`.

I'm using this OnBefore Transform script but still not getting results

```
// Updates the SN Account Expires field   
var n = source.u_accountexpires;  
var s = n.toString();  

// Only convert AD accountExpires values that begin with 1 (ex. 0 represents never expires)  
if (s.charAt(0) == 1) {  
    var dtUtil = new DateTimeUtils();
    var gDate = dtUtil.int8ToGlideDateTime(n);
    gDate.addDaysLocalTime(-1);
    target.u_account_expiration = gDate;  
}else if(!target.u_account_expiration.nil()) {  
    target.u_account_expiration = '';  
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `source.u_accountexpires` going into this? Also, what do you mean by "not getting results"?

Comment: source.u_accountexpires holds a date In AD and want o map it in user table.

Comment: Right, but it's just a number at that point right? Can you paste in a real value that you see that is not getting translated properly?